# JavaEE6 Web profile installation error 'The configuration has failed. Please see the output below'

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, asadmin

I am trying to install java ee 6 web profile on windows 7. The installer gives error msg during configuration step. The error is:

> The configuration has failed. Please
>   see the output below.

The problem is installer fail creating admin account through asadmin. As I also tried to make one manually after finishing installation but cmd shows following(same shown during configuration failure) error:

> The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

The command/path I used is:

*glassfish-install-dir\bin\asadmin create-domain domain-name*

The output it shows below on configuration step is:

CREATING DOMAIN

---

```
Executing command :D:\Java 6 EE\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\Users\babar\AppData\Local\Temp\java_ee_sdk-6u2-windows.exe2\asadminTmp5537629014448195896.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1
D:\Java 6 EE\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\Users\babar\AppData\Local\Temp\java_ee_sdk-6u2-windows.exe2\asadminTmp1045708641610025270.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: What is "the output below"? Could you add it to your post? The cmd-output is simply a path problem and not related to Glassfish.

Comment: I could put it here in the evening when at home after reproducing the error msg. I am at university now.thanx a lot

Comment: @Matt Handy : I updated OP with output below

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be related to your glassfish install dir which contains spaces (Java 6 EE). On Windows these pathes have to be surrounded by "...". Try to install glassfish in a path without spaces.

Comment: I got the same error today, but I have no spaces in the directory. However Glassfish tries to use C:\Users\tim\AppData\Local\Temp\java_ee_sdk-6u2-windows.exe, even though I installed everything on drive I.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was trying to install the Java EE 6 SDK without JDK 7 on a machine that did not already have the JDK. Problem solved by installing Java EE 6 SDK *with* JDK 7 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html).